# Boost.Python boost::shared_ptr no to python by value converter found

Tags: python, c++, boost, shared-ptr, boost-python

I have the given code,

In A.hpp

```
typedef boost::shared_ptr<A> APtr;
```

and

In B.hpp

```
typedef std::vector<APtr> APtrCollection;                      
typedef boost::shared_ptr<APtrCollection> APtrCollectionPtr;
APtrCollectionPtr a_ptr;

APtrCollectionPtr B::get_items() {
     return a_ptr;
}
```

In boost.python interface file

```
class_<B>("St")
        .def("get", get_st)
        .def("set", set_st)
        .add_property("items", &B::get_items)
;
```

The code compiles without errors, but when i run, i get error

```
     TypeError: 'No to_python (by-value) converter found for C++ type: boost::shared_ptr<std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<A>, std::allocator<boost::shared_ptr<A> > > >'
```

How to solve this problem ?

My boost version is: 1.57, 
python: Python 2.7.11 |Anaconda 2.4.1 (64-bit), 
gcc: gcc version 4.8.3 (GCC)

Answer (score 1):

You need to expose `A` and `APtrCollection` to `boost::python` first:

```
class_<A>("A")
    // You can put stuff here or just leave it blank
    ;

class_<APtrCollection>("APtrCollection")
    .def(vector_indexing_suite<APtrCollection>())
    ;
```

Now just proceed as before:

```
class_<B>("St")
    .def("get", get_st)
    .def("set", set_st)
    .add_property("items", &B::get_items)
    ;
```